# SQL: Pick the first occurence of first column with distinct value of second

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following values, and I would like to get the distinct values of acc_num with the top most ref_id. Can you advice how I can do this.

```
ref_id  acc_ num
 1234    H0456
 1235    H0456
 1236    H0987
 1237    H0987
 1238    H0741
```

So my result should be

```
ref_id acc_num
 1234   H0456
 1236   H0987
 1238   H0741
```

Comment: Hint : `GROUP BY` & `MIN()`.

Comment: Which SQL engine are you running? Yogesh is right though

Comment: try this: SELECT MIN(ref_id) FROM table GROUP BY (acc_num);

Comment: in ur question u say u want to get top most ref_id, but in ur sample result u have shown minimum ref_id per acc_num

Comment: Also, what do you mean by top most? The first record it finds? Or the lowest number? You may need ORDER BY as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use min aggregation

```
   selct cust_name,acc_num,ref_id from
   ( select acc_num,min(ref_id) as ref_id
    from tablename
    group by acc_num)a inner join customertable c on c.acc_num=a.acc_num
```

Comment: worked perfectly fa06.. Thank you so much. Can I ask you something.. I want to join the result with another table using a join but getting an error.

Comment: can you post that table information in your question then I may help you

Comment: I am using acc_num to get cus_name from another table but it says " c.cus_name is invalid in the select list becuase it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause

Comment: @EricDavid you will need to add it to the GROUP BY

Comment: @EricDavid, I've modified my answer you can check

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM `table`
group by acc_num order by ref_id
```

Comment: How does this help the OP *"pick first occurence of first column with distinct value"*?